# WatchKit Simulator periodically gets stuck on load Spinner

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm experiencing a similar issue as was posted previously in:

[WatchKit Simulator Won't Load App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711660/watchkit-simulator-wont-load-app)

My WatchApp seems to be loading okay (I'm watching step by step w/ NSLog), but the spinner (sometimes) never stops and the Watch interface (sometimes) never appears in the Simulator, i.e.:

[image: stuck-spinner]

I've tried some of the workarounds posted at the above URL (and I apologize for not being able to directly add my comments there) and they seem to work some of the time.
But I'm looking for confirmation that this is a bug in the XCode 6.4 Simulator code or perhaps an incompatibility with my older hardware? (I'm running latest version Yosemite & XCode but on an older mid 2009 Macbook Pro).

It just seems un-Apple like for a development environment to be this buggy. I keep thinking it's gotta be my code and not Apple's XCode Simulator?

Anyone else still encountering these kind of "spinner and not displaying Watch screen" in the Simulator?

Thank you for any input, the previously suggested workarounds seem to help some of the time but having to go thru that many steps with each compile & run cycle is making rapid iterative Watch development in the Simulator extremely frustrating.

Comment: I have the same problem, but the Watch app works perfectly in the simulator, but not on my actual Watch.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm still searching for a definitive answer, and not certain if there's an error in my code (or storyboard layout) or if the Simulator (and Watch hardware too) is just still buggy.
I did find the following Stackoverflow response helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083727/watchkit-not-calling-willactivate-method

"I've found that locking and unlocking the device (simulator) by typing Command-L will cause the willActivate method to be called. I hope you don't have to do that on a real Apple Watch."

Comment: In summary, locking and unlocking the Simulator (as referenced in my just previous comment) does stop the spinner and load the Watch app. I can now more smoothly go forward with development but would still like feedback/confirmation if this eternal spinner & lock/unlock fix is early Watch SDK bugginess or something I'm possibly still doing wrong in Xcode and my code.