# Apple Watch simulator stuck loading in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, apple-watch

When I run WatchKit App, Apple Watch simulator stuck loading. Like this,

[image]

But, I can run that for the first time, that is, it is the first time after restarting iOS simulator.

If you quit iOS simulator and then restart that, you can run Apple Watch simulator only once.

Now I need to restart simulator every time. That's really annoying.
Is there any good method for this situation?

---

Version 8.4 (SimulatorApp-565.9 CoreSimulator-117.15)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by paragraph under the image: "I can run that for the first time."  A more precise sequence of events might help people answer this question better.

Comment: You ever get any of these workarounds to help?

Comment: I have missed your comment. I got it. I'll add the details.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me, I am usually successful after the second or third launch of the app (without quitting Xcode or the simulator).  This has been the case with both Xcode 6 and Xcode 7.

If you provide more details, I can probably refine this answer better.   **Here are some things that may work for you, depending upon whether you're running Xcode 7 or 6:**

- Try deleting and re-creating the target scheme: [SO: Apple Watch Simulator Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201559/apple-watch-simulator-issue)
- A variant of the above: Tutorial on Apple Watch from [Natasha the Robot](http://natashatherobot.com/hello-world-watchkit-app/)
- Some suggestions that have worked for some people on Xcode 6.x: [SO: watchkit simulator won't load app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711660/watchkit-simulator-wont-load-app)

**Regardless of the work-around, if this isn't due to user error, perhaps the best thing to do is to submit a bug report to Apple.**

Here are some suggested files to include when submitting a [Radar Bug Report](http://bugreport.apple.com) to Apple (See this [developer form thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15210)):

> ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/[UDID of Watch]/system.log
>
> ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/[UDID of Phone]/system.log
>
> ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/*.log
>
> A sysdiagnose taken just after reproducing this issue.

Comment: Oh, that's terrible. I hope this improve. Thanks!

Comment: If it happens consistently, go ahead and file a bug report with Apple.  BTW I had similar problems with the Android emulator)even with acceleration).  What sort of development  machine are you using?

Comment: Yes, I thinking of submitting a bug report. I am using Xcode as you know.

Comment: Watch support in the simulator in Xcode 6 was done completely differently than the version in Xcode 7.  I suggest you try using the latest Xcode 7 beta.

Comment: I have the same issue, but this is not an answer, sorry.

Comment: Sorry but I was doing my best to help.  I gave my workaround for what I understood the question to be.  If there is a better workaround, someone will surely post it; if not, the right answer is to report it to Apple.

Comment: I highly recommend you delete this answer before it gets down voted further. Not a threat, helpful advice.